# Spring and Hibernate Transaction does not work for mass save operations

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, crud

I am doing mass save with JpaRepository.I used @Transactional but it didn't work.I summarize the process I did:
I have two Enties

- THeaderEntity
- TDetailsEntity

First of all, I save the TheaderEntity because the THeaderEntity's information will be used in the TDetailsEntity (One To Many, CrudRepository.save(), 1 Header for 50 Details)
Then turn and save in the TDetailsEntity's loop.I want the entire process rollback if any registry gets an error.

```
@Transactional
public Result createTdetailsFromHeaderId(String token, String headerId, DetailRequests detailRequests)
```

I used @Transactional but only the record that received the error was rollback.

Comment: Is the code where you call createTdetailsFromHeaderId also transactional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer why only 1 record is rolled back you might look into Spring's transactional logic - I suspect from your description that 1 transaction is opened for every save but an easy way to work on this is:

- Adjust the `@OneToMany` relationship to [`cascade`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#cascade()) the persisting of entities.
- Create the appropriate entities (1 `THeaderEntity` and 50 `TDetailsEntity` having all object references set correctly).
- `save` the `THeaderEntity` that then should cascade the persisting to its `TDetailsEntity`.